# Can you upload historical metrics to Cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

We use AWS Cloudwatch Metrics and the associated dashboards a lot. Sometimes we want to add a new visualisation, but now we can only find the metric from our first PutMetricData onwards. We however often have the data retrospectively, just not uploaded at the time.

Can you retrospectively upload metrics to Cloudwatch?

Comment: Can't you use Cloudwatch custom metrics and pushed them?